# What is difference between ionic-header-bar and ion-header-bar ? When I must use each of them?

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new to ionic. I have encountered following two directives :-

`ion-header-bar` and `ionic-header-bar`

I am confused regarding, when each of these directives are used ? I have tried playing with them

```
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced bar-subheader">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-chevron-left"></button>
        <h2 class="title">Sub Header</h2>
    </ion-header-bar>
```

It shows the following UI :-
[image]

But, when I try

```
        <ionic-header-bar class=" bar-balanced bar-subheader">
            <button class="button button-icon icon ion-chevron-left"></button>
            <h2 class="title">Sub Header</h2>
        </ionic-header-bar>
```

UI changes to following :-
[image]
So, what's the use of ionic-header-bar directive ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [ionic framework docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionHeaderBar/) there is no `ionic-header-bar` directive. In that way there is no use of it as an ionic UI element. It results in a plane HTML element. All ionic directives starts with an `ion-` element tag.

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced bar-subheader"></ion-header-bar>
```

Answer (score 2):

where you have seen that:

```
 <ionic-header-bar class=" bar-balanced bar-subheader">
 </ionic-header-bar>
```

I think it does not exist and the **correct code** is:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced bar-subheader">
</ion-header-bar>
```

(I Agree with lin)